# How to set the same value for a range in an array in Java in one line?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Say I have an array of 100 elements and I want a certain range of indices to have a certain value. For example indices 0 through 10 will have "Bob," indices 11 - 57 will have "Jake," and indices 58-99 will have "John". Is that possible to do in one line? Thank you

Comment: Just because you _can_ do something in one line, doesn't mean you _should_

Comment: Check `Arrays.fill()` method

Comment: You want to fill an existing Array? In one line? Look at [`Array.setAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(T%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntFunction)): `Arrays.setAll(yourArray, i -> i < 11 ? "Bob" : i < 58 ? "Jake" : "John");`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You ***could*** use an `IntStream.range(int, int)` to generate the range, then map to a `String` with nested ternaries. Like,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .mapToObj(i -> i < 11 ? "Bob" : i < 58 ? "Jake" : "John")
        .toArray()));
```

Comment: Arrays.setAll might be better for an existing array. Or even a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for `Bob`.

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) myArray[i]="Bob";
```

I'd write a method:

```
static void fillRange(String[] arr, int from, int to, String val){
    for(int i=from; i<=to; i++) arr[i]=val;
}
```

and then call it:

```
 fillRange(myArray, 0, 10, "Bob"); fillRange(myArray, 11, 57, "Jake");...
```

But you must make sure that your array contains the required range already:

```
 int arrLength = 99;
 ....
 String[] myArray = new String[arrLength];
```

Comment: Or just use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,int,int,java.lang.Object)) instead of rolling your own fillRange. It even has the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages it would be simple to set up all the parameters in a tuple and evaluate them as a list comprehension. However, Java isn't really well suited for doing this type of thing in a single statement.

```
Arrays.stream(new Object[] {
    new Object[] {0,10,"Bob"},
    new Object[] {11,57,"Jake"},
    new Object[] {58,99,"John"}
}).forEach(objs -> Arrays.fill(myArray,
            (int)(((Object[]) objs)[0]),
            ((int)(((Object[]) objs)[1]))+1,
            ((Object[]) objs)[2])
);
```

Or if you are willing to abuse the ternary operator, you could use this lovely gem (credits to [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn)):

```
Arrays.setAll(myArray, i -> i <= 10 ? "Bob" : i <= 57 ? "Jake" : "John");
```

However, the moral of the story is: Just because you *can* do something in one line, doesn't mean you *should*. Clarity is more important.